# Force partition id with parted

Tags: lvm, parted

I want to create a LVM partition using the `parted` command. So far I did:

```
# set up the partition table
parted /dev/sda mklabel msdos

#/dev/sda1 (boot) :
parted /dev/sda mkpart primary ext2 1MiB 513MiB

#/dev/sda2 (LVM) :
parted /dev/sda mkpart extended 513MiB 100%

# set up partitions' flags
parted /dev/sda set 1 boot on
parted /dev/sda set 2 lvm on
```

But I get a "W95 Ext'd (LBA)" partition (type f), see [fdisk -l output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K79j.png). I would like a "Linux LVM" partition (type 8e).

How can I force the partition ID using the parted command?
.

Answer (score 1):

The type on an [extended partition MUST be 0F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#PID_0Fh). You can't directly use the extended partition as an LVM PV. Instead, you need to make an extended partition, then make a logical partition *inside* the extended partition. The [parted manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_chapter/parted_2.html#SEC18) has an example of how to make a logical partition. (Note: logical partitions are not to be confused with logical volumes.)

Extended and logical partitions were created to hack around MS-DOS's limit of 4 partitions per disk, which is why this is so painful.